# I got this crash message "Message sent to deallocated instance"

Tags: iphone, objective-c

My app crash giving this follow.

```
*** -[MyItem respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x18bc9f0
```

Is there any way to know the position of release and retain message was called?

Thanks!

Comment: Use ARC and dont release anything. (except for core foundation objects of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. **Instruments** will tell you every retain and release that was called. It's up to you to balance them.